# Font-Awesome icons not displaying content: overwritten

Tags: drupal, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome icons on my drupal website. However none of the icons is showing up in any or the browsers (IE, FF or Chrome). When I check the css with F12

<strike>content: \f045;</strike>

has a line through it. When looking at the Computed settings it shows as

```
content: normal;
```

Also I can't see anywhere in the display where it gets overwritten, can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Seemed to have been related to the theme that I was using. Uploaded the latest version and the icons "magically" appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a few places when I upgraded from version 3.2 to 4 but only where I had specified just the class/icon name, e.g.

```
<span id="userEmailLockToggleButtonIcon" class="fa-lock"></span>
```

Adding the class 'fa' fixed it for me.

```
<span id="userEmailLockToggleButtonIcon" class="fa fa-lock"></span>
```

Will